# Corrupted smart group?

Tags: smartgroups

I noticed that a smart group I created a while back was not displaying the correct records (some were missing).

I rebuilt the cache, but to no avail.

In addition, when I did an advanced search with the same criteria, it did display the correct records.

The only difference I can notice in criteria is an extra "…AND…":

Old smart group:

```
...AND...
Status = Regular Attender OR Active Member
```

New advanced search:

```
Status = Regular Attender OR Active Member
```

One more data point: when I edit the old smart group criteria and remove all criteria, it only returns a subset of our database – not all records (which, I believe, it should).

Is the old smart group corrupted? What are the next steps in troubleshooting?

We're on CiviCRM 4.6.4 and Drupal 7.38.

Answer (score 5):

I would first check that contacts haven't been manually added to or removed from the smart group. To do this you'll probably need access to the database in order to interrogate the tables. Even though they are smart groups you can still manually add and remove contacts from them and that might be why your seeing unexpected results.

The second test would be to create a new smart group based on the criteria you want and see if you get the result

Comment: Thank you. I actually did create a new smart group based on the criteria I wanted and it returned the correct results (which were more than the results of the old smart group).